# Can't assign Static Double Pointer variable

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, pointers, double-pointer

I can't seem to assign a static double pointer variable. Am i doing something wrong?

Using .Net 4.7.2

```
static unsafe float** pointers = (float**)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(float) * 32);

static unsafe void Main(string[] args)
{
       var i = pointers == default; // false but displays 0x0000000000000000

       // stil the same
       pointers = (float**)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(float) * 32);

       // works - 0x00000213094bc7c0
       float** test = (float**)Marshal.AllocHGlobal(sizeof(float) * 32);
}
```

[image: example]
Debug- 64x

Is this the correct behaviour or is it happening to anyone else?

Comment: Not really my thing but shouldn't that be `static unsafe float** pointers`? And isn't that needed to even compile? And I'm interested in how you have managed to get away without `unsafe` blocks around the code or an `unsafe` in the `Main` method declaration?

Comment: @stuartd edited: unsafe was in the base class Program.

Comment: Ah, fair enough. Can't repro though with this code in 4.5 or 4.7.2 or 4.8 - does this code reproduce the issue for you?

Comment: Yes, pic added.

Comment: Are your pointers 32 bits or 64 bits?  floats are 32 bits so it looks like you are allocated 32 pointers to float numbers.  The size of the pointers will vary depending on the compiler options.  Only 64 bit compiler options will be 64 bits.  It looks like you are assigned 0x0000000000000000 which is 64 bits.  I think the error is the pointer are only 32 bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like purely debugger problem: in  both cases memory is allocated, you can cast `pointers` to `IntPtr` and it is not 0.

Issue is reproducible with the code you provided:
[image]

I was able to see an address of `pointers` when turned off `Use Managed Compatibility Mode` in settings:
[image]